# Python matplotlib colorbar axis offset string position/location

Tags: python, label, matplotlib, contour, colorbar

I want to make a contour-plot with a horizontal colorbar. The bar should have labels with scientific notation. Everything goes well in the code below. However, now I want to change the position of the multiplicator specifying the scientific scale. I think this is called an offset string by the axis. Does anybody know how to do this? I want to place the multiplicator right of the colorbar (as if it would be an additional label).

```
#http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib import rc

# make up data.
seed(0)
npts = 200
x = uniform(-2,2,npts)
y = uniform(-2,2,npts)
z = x*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
# define grid
xi = np.linspace(-2.1,2.1,100)
yi = np.linspace(-2.1,2.1,200)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi,interp='linear')

rcParams['axes.formatter.limits'] = (-1,1)

plt.figure()
CS    = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,25,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
bar    = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal') # draw colorbar
# plot data points.
plt.xlim(-2,2)
plt.ylim(-2,2)
plt.title('griddata test (%d points)' % npts)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

From your code above, just use:

```
bar.ax.xaxis.get_offset_text().set_position((x,y))
```

where `(x,y)` is the location where you want the text in axes coordinates (e.g. `x=0` is the left hand side and `x=1` is the right hand side).

Also note that setting the y-coordinate won't do anything in this case, as the location in the y-direction is controlled by the axis padding, etc.  (You can change it, but it's slightly more complicated.)

Comment: Kington, thank you for your answer, I just hoped that one can change the position such, that it appears beside the colorbar (not only its horizontal position but also the vertical one). The best thing would we if one could integrate it into the label of the colorbar (to say the color means A in units of B where B includes the order of magnitude). It just takes a lot of space if the scale multiplier is put below the colorbar. Do you know any solution? From looking inside the code of matplotlib I found no way how to do this.

Comment: The y-coordinate can be changed by changing the padding via ax.xaxis.OFFSETTEXTPAD

Answer (score 2):

I found that that command lets you directly work on the label position.

```
bar.ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(3, .5)
```

It took me some iterations to position text correctly, since I found working colorbar coordinates completely unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion from Joe Kington above, I found the following modification most easy:

```
bar.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
bar.ax.set_ylabel('YourLabel', rotation='horizontal')
```

Comment: Small mistake here: the method for changing the label position is `set_label_position`. The first line should thus read `bar.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')`.